# Some matrices are real numbers?

Tags: matrices, fake-proofs

Suppose $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $A$ is a matrix, and $I$ is the identity matrix. Then,
$$
I a = I a \\
A = Ia\\
IA = IIa \\
IA=Ia\\
\implies  A=a
$$

Comment: What is your justification for the last step?

Comment: $IA$ is the same as $A$ but $Ia$ is not the same as $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is an invertible matrix and $A$ and $B$ are matrices (all the matrices here are square matrices with the same size), then, yes, $MA=MB\implies A=B$. But in the equality $\operatorname{Id}A=\operatorname{Id}a$, $\operatorname{Id}a$ is *not* a product of two matrices. So, you cannot apply that property here.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that multiplication of a matrix by a scalar ($Ia$) and multiplication of matrices ($IA$) are really different operations although the notations look the same.

That said, the matrix $Ia$ behaves just like the scalar $a$ in some ways, and
the two are often identified.  Thus $(Ia)M = a M = M (Ia)$ if both $M$ and $I$ are $n \times n$ matrices.